# Argument type IOrderedQueryable does not match the corresponding member type IOrderedEnumerable (LINQ to SQL)

Tags: c#, linq, ef-core-3.1

I'm trying to run this LINQ-to-SQL query

```
var sourceFilters = await _context.Sources.Where(s => s.CreatedBy == userId).Select(s => new  {
            SourceId = s.Id,
            SourceName = s.Name,
            Models = s.Vehicles.Select(v => new VehicleKeys()
                        {
                            Model = v.Model,
                            Code = v.Code,
                            RegistrationNumber = v.RegistrationNumber
                        }).Distinct().OrderBy(k => k.Model).ThenBy(k => k.Code).ThenBy(k => k.RegistrationNumber)
        }).ToListAsync()
```

`s.Vehicles` is a navigation property

But I get the following Exception:

```
Argument type 'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable`1[MyProject.Infrastructure.Services.SourceService+VehicleKeys]' does not match the corresponding member type 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable`1[MyProject.Infrastructure.Services.SourceService+VehicleKeys]'
```

I tried adding `.ToList()` after all of the `OrderBy` calls, but then the resulting `sourceFilters.Models` collection only has a single element (even if I add `Include(s=>s.Vehicles)` to `_context.Sources`)

I also tried turning anonymous type into a normal type `SourceKeys`, but if I define `Models` property as a `IOrderedQueryable` or `IQueryable` - I get a compile time error. If I define it as a `IEnumerable` or `IOrderedEnumerable` - I get an `Argument types do not match` exception

Another thing I attempted was adding `AsQueryable()`, right after `s.Vehicles`, after `Distinct()` or after all of the `OrderBy` clauses. In the first and second cases I get the following exception:

```
Argument type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[MyProject.Infrastructure.Services.SourceService+VehicleKeys]' does not match the corresponding member type 'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable`1[MyProject.Infrastructure.Services.SourceService+VehicleKeys]'
```

In the third case I get:

```
Argument type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyProject.Infrastructure.Services.SourceService+VehicleKeys]' does not match the corresponding member type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[MyProject.Infrastructure.Services.SourceService+VehicleKeys]'
```

I've also tried both having a named type for the elements of the `sourceFilters` collection, and adding `AsQueryable()`

If I have `Models` be `IOrderedQueryable<VehicleKeys>` and put `AsQueryable()` after `s.Vehicles` or after `Distinct()` I get the `Argument types do not match` exception. If I put `AsQueryable()` after all of the `OrderBy()` clauses - I get a compile error.

If I have `Models` be `IQueryable<VehicleKeys>` I get `Argument types do not match` exception, no matter where I put `AsQueryable()`.

At this point I have absolutely no ideas on what else to try. I can work around the problem by doing the ordering on the client-side, but I would prefer to things like ordering on the SQL Server, to leverage the benefits of indexation, and I also really want to understand what's the cause of the problem, so if similar problems were to pop up in the future I would be able to deal with them.

Edit:
Models:

```
public class Source {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }
}

public class Vehicle {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string RegistrationNumber { get; set; }
    public int? SourceId { get; set; }
    public Source Source { get; set; }
    //some other properties
}
```

`{Model, Code, RegistrationNumber, SourceId, /* some other properties*/}` have an index and an unique constraint

```
private class VehicleKeys {
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string RegistrationNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Try to put `ToList()` after last `ThenBy`. Linq to Sql is a little bit outdated technology, but I'm trying to help from query translation perspective.

Comment: @Svyatoslav I tried that. In that case the `Models` collection only has a single element

Comment: I didn't think LINQ to SQL had navigation properties. Are you using EF / EF Core? What version?

Comment: @NetMage EF Core 3.1

Comment: Adding `AsQueryable` is almost never the right thing to do. Having `Models` be `IEnumerable<VehicleKeys>` have you tried adding `AsEnumerable()`?

Comment: Show model classes and `VehicleKeys` also.

Comment: @JohnDiGriz, do not use `Linq to Sql` in such questions, it is library which is not comparable to EF Core.

Comment: @Svyatoslav thanks, I was under assumption that any Linq that's querying SQL databases is LINQ-to-SQL

Comment: @NetMage I did not. Is there a reason to expect it to behave differently from `.ToList()`?

Comment: Try to remove `Distinct()` and tell me how it works.

Comment: 1. Based on the error message, your (guessed at) data type for `Models` was not `IEnumerable<VehicleKeys>`. That could be the root of your issue but 2. EF sometimes has funny ideas about converting `ToList`, `AsEnumerable`, especially in nested sub-queries - worth trying each.

Comment: @NetMage `AsEnumerable` didn't help, the resulting list only has a single element

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv without `Distinct()` and with ordering and `AsEnumerable` it throws `System.Reflection.InvalidFilterCriteriaException: Specified filter criteria was invalid.`

Comment: Try the [following](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oI0EhK) query and let me know how it works.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv the resulting `Models` list is not sorted

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Oh, my bad,I forgot to remove `Distinct()`, without it your query works fine. However I do need distinct values in the `Models` list

Comment: So, you can't use `Distinct` in Eager Loading query. Not sure if it is possible in EF Core 7.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv you mean you can't call Distinct on related entities?

Comment: I mean Eager Loading queries. When you load with main entity a list of detail entities - it is Eager Loading query. It has no direct SQL translation and EF Core is trying to invent something, sometimes (frequently) it fails. If you have complex query for loading details in such query - it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to split this query to two parts. One should execute Eager Loading query, second post process records on the client side:

```cs
var rawData = await _context.Sources
    .Where(s => s.CreatedBy == userId)
    .Select(s => new  
    {
        SourceId = s.Id,
        SourceName = s.Name,
        Models = s.Vehicles
            .Select(v => new 
            {
                Model = v.Model,
                Code = v.Code,
                RegistrationNumber = v.RegistrationNumber
            }).ToList()
    })
    .ToListAsync();

var sourceFilters = rawData
    .Select(s => new  
    {
        s.SourceId,
        s.SourceName,
        Models = s.Models
            .Distinct()
            .OrderBy(k => k.Model)
            .ThenBy(k => k.Code)
            .ThenBy(k => k.RegistrationNumber)
            .Select(v => new VehicleKeys()
            {
                Model = v.Model,
                Code = v.Code,
                RegistrationNumber = v.RegistrationNumber
            }).ToList()
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I'm hesitant on doing in-memory ordering, because that means I give up any performance improvements from database indexation. In the end I decided to use the query you linked to in the comments to query the database, and calling Distinct() during the client-side processing

Comment: You are talking about Non Translatable to the SQL LINQ query. Eager Loading has no direct SQL translation. Performance is lost exactly when you load detail entitles.  Even they sorted, non sorted. EF Core usually sort detail records on the client side as in this answer.

Comment: The SQL query that is sent to the database has an ORDER BY clause in it

Comment: So, how it helps if you need to apply `Distinct` later? `Distinct` returns unordered sequence.

Comment: `Distinct` is not guaranteed to preserve order, but its Linq-to-Objects implementation does preserve it. Relying on the implementation details is not good, but I don't think it would a problem in this case

Comment: I do not understand why we are talking about obvious things. My solution works for you or not?